# Issue in CSS perspective

Tags: css, web, frontend, perspective

I created this [snippet](https://codepen.io/MohammedFuad/pen/MvJMqr) using css perspective which I am going to use in a project, but I have a problem with the first row of boxes.

In the first row of boxes, I need top borders lines of each box to be curved like bottom borders lines.
Like the second row, which is curved from both [top & bottom].

Some of what I used:

```
-webkit-perspective: /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-perspective-origin: /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
perspective:
perspective-origin:
```

**And my [snippet link](https://codepen.io/MohammedFuad/pen/MvJMqr) is here.**

Thanks.

Comment: it looks fine, can you clarify your issue ?

Comment: the top lines borders of the first row are straight, I want them to be diagonal like the bottom lines, and exactly like the second row tops and bottoms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might set a negative origin to your main box *(if i understood the issue)*:

```
perspective-origin: 60% -50%;
```

```css
#main-box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 43%;
  top: 30%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 150px;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  -webkit-perspective: 150px;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 10% 10%;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  perspective: 700px;
  perspective-origin: 60% -50%;
}

.box {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(20deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotateX(20deg);
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.box.second-row {
  top: 150px;
}

.box:nth-of-type(1),
.box:nth-of-type(6) {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(20deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(30deg);
}

.box:nth-of-type(1):hover,
.box:nth-of-type(6):hover {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(100px);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(30deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.box:nth-of-type(2),
.box:nth-of-type(7) {
  left: 180px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(15deg) translateZ(-68px);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(15deg) translateZ(-68px);
}

.box:nth-of-type(2):hover,
.box:nth-of-type(7):hover {
  left: 175px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(15deg) translateZ(100px);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(15deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.box:nth-of-type(3),
.box:nth-of-type(8) {
  left: 340px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(-90px);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(-90px);
}

.box:nth-of-type(3):hover,
.box:nth-of-type(8):hover {
  left: 340px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.box:nth-of-type(4),
.box:nth-of-type(9) {
  left: 500px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-15deg) translateZ(-68px);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-15deg) translateZ(-68px);
}

.box:nth-of-type(4):hover,
.box:nth-of-type(9):hover {
  left: 505px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-15deg) translateZ(100px);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-15deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.box:nth-of-type(5),
.box:nth-of-type(10) {
  left: 680px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-20deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-30deg);
}

.box:nth-of-type(5):hover,
.box:nth-of-type(10):hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-20deg) translateZ(100px);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.box:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: blue;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-box">
  <div class="box">BOX</div>
  <div class="box">BOX</div>
  <div class="box">BOX</div>
  <div class="box">BOX</div>
  <div class="box">BOX</div>

  <div class="box second-row">BOX</div>
  <div class="box second-row">BOX</div>
  <div class="box second-row">BOX</div>
  <div class="box second-row">BOX</div>
  <div class="box second-row">BOX</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BdWBNO or even more https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ayJodZ